# Ruby Openid connect library with client consumption example

Tags: ruby, openid-connect

I'm looking for a ruby openid connect client library with a straight forward code example of using it. I found one library [here](https://github.com/nov/openid_connect) and it's examples are based on rails but I'm not familiar with rails that much and I'm not successful in finding a clear example of a ruby client code example elsewhere, hope if someone can help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. The gem you linked to is the only one I can find that implements OpenID Connect, and it looks like a fine implementation -- there's even two live apps demoing both parties, with code on GitHub -- but literally zero documentation explaining how to use it.  Surely there are Ruby people out there building apps that support OpenID Connect, but I have no idea how, or why no one has documented the gem.

Comment: Any luck with the implementation?

Comment: https://github.com/jjbohn/omniauth-openid-connect. I've found this easy to use for getting an id_token but it's got plenty of bugs for discovery, access/refresh tokens, and i've had some SSL certificate issues. It also has a spotty release schedule. It uses nov/openid_connect but it follows the omniauth pattern (which is easier to understand IMO). I'm looking for another solution but find nov/openid_connect a bit obscure

Comment: I'd like to add that many of the implementations are too verbose, not very friendly (ie, they require you to know all of the jargon of openid connect).  It would be nice to have a "transparent" library which could enable downloading the "ServiceAccount" flow of google by just handing it the config file you download from google (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Comment: Use omniauth - it's great. We just did an OIDC project using omniauth, and got it working quickly for Google, Amazon and Microsoft OIDC servers.