# openid-connect client in ruby with example code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid-connect

I want to read data from an API which requires authorization with openid-connect. My client should be written in ruby, so I can use it in a task to import data into my rails app.

I am given a configuration under `theapi/.well-known/openid-configuration` along with a `client_id` and a `client_secret`.

Having never worked with openid before I did some research an found the following gems that might help to obtain an auth token:

- https://github.com/nov/openid_connect
- https://github.com/m0n9oose/omniauth_openid_connect

Both gems lack of any documentation or examples to get started, in fact I am not even sure if they are useful for my case.

Also there is a similar SO-post, but it's five years old with zero answers:
[Ruby Openid connect library with client consumption example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397820/ruby-openid-connect-library-with-client-consumption-example)

Could anybody help me out with a simple example on how to authorize against openid_connect in ruby, possibly using one of the mentioned gems?

Comment: any updates or answer?

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal  Were you able to find any documentation or example?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a nice tutorial to solve this challenge [FusionAuth](https://fusionauth.io/blog/2020/12/14/how-to-securely-implement-oauth-rails)

You require these 2 gems in your gemfile:
`gem 'jwt'` and
`gem 'oauth2'`

You will also be able to initialize the OAuth Client while replacing actual values of your Identity Server:

```
@oauth_client = OAuth2::Client.new(Rails.configuration.x.oauth.client_id,
                                   Rails.configuration.x.oauth.client_secret,
                                   authorize_url: '/oauth2/authorize',
                                   site: Rails.configuration.x.oauth.idp_url,
                                   token_url: '/oauth2/token',
                                   redirect_uri: Rails.configuration.x.oauth.redirect_uri)
```

With the OAuthClient initalised you can be able to perform your desired OAuth Flow.

For Authorization with **password_credentials** you can use:

```
response = @oauth_client.client_credentials.get_token
token = response.token
```

You can find more Authorization Type References here: [OAuth2 Docs](https://tiabas.github.io/oauth2-client/)

These two resources should enable you to complete your integration with any IdentityServer. Hope these resources stay updated.